# Flood Fill using matlab

Tags: matlab, flood-fill

I am new in MATLAB, I am trying to implement flood filling using this [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill#Stack-based_recursive_implementation_.28Four-way.29) in matlab, I dont know what I did wrong may be I didnt used recursive function right, but still I dont whats going wrong and this code make my matlab close
I am using the following code I am trying to debug it since morning but failed to find the problem

```
function [ colored_Image ] = floodFill( image, target_Loc_x, target_Loc_y, targetColor, replacementColor )
colored_Image = image;

if (target_Loc_x >= 1) && (target_Loc_x <= size(image,1)) && (target_Loc_y >= 1) && (target_Loc_y <= size(image,2))
    if image(target_Loc_x,target_Loc_y) == targetColor
        colored_Image(target_Loc_x,target_Loc_y) = replacementColor;
        colored_Image = floodFill(colored_Image,target_Loc_x ,target_Loc_y + 1, targetColor, replacementColor); 
        colored_Image = floodFill(colored_Image,target_Loc_x + 1,target_Loc_y, targetColor, replacementColor);
        colored_Image = floodFill(colored_Image,target_Loc_x,target_Loc_y - 1, targetColor, replacementColor);
        colored_Image = floodFill(colored_Image,target_Loc_x - 1,target_Loc_y, targetColor, replacementColor);
    end

end


end
```

calling this function using

```
image = floodFill(im,1,1,0,127);
imshow(image);
```

im is my matrix image of 200 by 200 I want my black color(0) to grey color(127), any help will be thankful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably hitting Matlab's recursion limit. My computer doesn't crash, but generates this error:

> Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached. Use set(0,'RecursionLimit',N)
>   to change the limit.  Be aware that exceeding your available stack
>   space can crash MATLAB and/or your computer.

The way around this is to rewrite floodFill so it does not use recursion. There are some [alternative algorithms on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill#Alternative_implementations).

Also: [aardvarkk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14238692/1339280) makes an important point about Matlab's [column-major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Column-major_order) indexing. You can fix your function by swapping all x and y variables.

Answer (score 3):

I believe there are two things wrong with this:

a) You appear to be indexing the `image` matrix in the order `(x,y)`. MATLAB matrices are in column order, so you have to (unintuitively) index them in the order `(y,x)`. So the line:

`image(target_Loc_x,target_Loc_y)`

should probably be:

`image(target_Loc_y,target_Loc_x)`

Same goes for when you set the value in the colored image. Note also that `size(image,1)` will give the size in the `y` direction, not `x`!

b) You're using a recursive function to do a very simple operation. It very quickly hits MATLAB's recursion limit. In a 200x200 image, you'll have a stack of calls 40,000 deep, and MATLAB only allows a recursion limit of 500 by default. Why not try something like this instead:

```
colored_image = image;
colored_image(colored_image == targetColor) = replacementColor;
```

Comment: The code snippet at the end won't work for flood fill. It will change all pixels with the target color instead of just connected pixels.

Comment: @shoelzer Good point. I had misinterpreted the original code snippet to fill the whole image anyway, but you're right -- it will only actually do anything if the first pixel that you select is of the target colour.

Answer (score 2):

```
    %(assume your image is loaded into img and you are filling with 'value')

function flood(x,y,img,value)

    %MATLAB doesnt have a friendly queue ? use java   
    import java.util.LinkedList
    q = LinkedList();

    %flood fill image 
    initial = img(y,x);

    q.add([y, x]);

    while q.size() > 0

        pt = q.removeLast();
        y = pt(1);
        x = pt(2);

        if (img(y+1, x) == initial) 
            img(y+1,x) = value;
            q.add([y+1, x]); 
        end
        if (img(y-1, x) == initial) 
            img(y-1,x) = value;
            q.add([y-1, x]); 
        end
        if (img(y, x+1) == initial) 
            img(y,x+1) = value;
            q.add([y, x+1]); 
        end
        if (img(y, x-1) == initial) 
            img(y,x-1) = value;
            q.add([y, x-1]); 
        end
    end
end
```

Because matlab has a very low recursion limit, I never had any luck with flood fill using recursive calls.  Also, because it doesn't seem to have a proper queue (please correct me if I am wrong) its easier to just import one from java.

This is not doing any bounds checks (so will fail if the flood hits the edge...The easy fix is to put a border around your image or just range check x and y before indexing img.

Answer (score 1):

A few fixes to @Jason's answer - I've added the bounds check, a guard that the fill colour is different to the initial colour (otherwise that's an infinite recursion) and return the result. Works but is slow.

```
function img = flood(x,y,img,value)
    % http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14238083/flood-fill-using-matlab
    import java.util.LinkedList
    q = LinkedList();

    initial = img(y,x);
    dims = size(img);
    if (value == initial) 
        error('cant flood fill as initial==value');
    end

    q.add([y, x]);

    while q.size() > 0

        pt = q.removeLast();
        y = pt(1);
        x = pt(2);

        if (y < dims(1) && img(y+1, x) == initial) % step down
            img(y+1,x) = value;
            q.add([y+1, x]); 
        end
        if (y > 1 && img(y-1, x) == initial) % step up
            img(y-1,x) = value;
            q.add([y-1, x]); 
        end
        if (x < dims(2) && img(y, x+1) == initial) % step right
            img(y,x+1) = value;
            q.add([y, x+1]); 
        end
        if (x > 1 && img(y, x-1) == initial) % step left
            img(y,x-1) = value;
            q.add([y, x-1]); 
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I've merged bugfix from anonymous commenter. Thanks